# TypeScript Generics: Type argument inference in generic interfaces vs generic functions

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble understanding why instances of generic interfaces cannot dynamically infer type arguments whereas generic functions can.

Consider the following interface:

```
interface Sortable<T> {
  arr: T[];
  sort: (arr: T[]) => T[];
}
```

When I create an instance of `Sortable`, I am required to pass a value for `T` since it is a required type argument.

```
// Error: Generic type 'Sortable<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
const sortableEmpty: Sortable = {
  arr: [],
  sort: (arr) => arr,
};

// Works as expected
const sortableNumbers: Sortable<number> = {
  arr: [2, 0, 1],
  sort: (numbers) =>
    numbers.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a > b) {
        return 1;
      } else if (a < b) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    }),
};

interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

// Works with complex data types
const sortablePeople: Sortable<Person> = {
  arr: [
    { name: "Charlie", age: 32 },
    { name: "Bob", age: 32 },
    { name: "Alice", age: 8 },
  ],
  sort: (people) =>
    people.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.age > b.age) {
        return 1;
      } else if (a.age < b.age) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
      }
    }),
};
```

My expectation would be that type arguments in generic interfaces would not need to be explicitly assigned unless they were narrowing the inferred type of the argument, similar to how type arguments in generic functions are inferred:

```
const applySort = <T>(arr: T[], sort: (arr: T[]) => T[]) => sort(arr);

// No explicit type argument needed!
applySort(sortableNumbers.arr, sortableNumbers.sort);
// Error: Type 'Person' is not assignable to type 'number'.
applySort(sortablePeople.arr, sortableNumbers.sort);
```

What confuses me is that it seems entirely possible for TypeScript to infer type arguments in generic interfaces. By using a generic interface as a parameter in a generic function, I am able to get TypeScirpt to infer and enforce type arguments on generic interfaces:

```
const identity = <T>(sortable: Sortable<T>) => sortable;

// Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
identity({
  arr: [2, 0, 1],
  sort: (arr: string[]) => arr,
});

// Works as intended
identity({
  arr: [2, 0, 1],
  sort: (arr: number[]) => arr,
});
```

Any help in understanding why generic interfaces and generic functions behave differently when inferring type arguments would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's just not a feature of the language at the moment. Though I think the `satisfies` operator which is [in discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920) might help eventually. Then you may be able to do something like `const foo = {/*...*/} satisfies Foo<unknown>`

Comment: When you call a generic function the compiler does indeed attempt to infer its generic type parameters.  And there is indeed no such analogous feature for generic types; it seems you expect a variable initialization like `const v: F = i` to automatically infer any type parameters in `F`, and this doesn't happen.  I'm not sure it's possible to authoritatively answer *why*, though.  That's just not the way generic types work; the scope of the type parameter on a generic function is different from the scope on a generic type.

Comment: There are various proposals that might address this; the satisfies operator may or may not give you an `infer` like ability (as requested in [ms/TS#38349](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38349), closed as a duplicate of [ms/TS#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481)), closed as a preamble to [ms/TS#47920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920)) but this is not there yet.

Comment: Could you clarify what kind of answer you'd consider sufficient here?  "Different language features behave differently" seems too general to serve as an answer, but there may be no more specific answer that isn't just conjecture.  Opinions without citations aren't generally on topic here, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for pointing me toward those proposals. I guess I was ultimately trying to confirm whether there was an underlying concept with generics that I may have been missing.

Comment: I think my only remaining question (which will come down to opinion) is how do people deal with generic interfaces with lots of type arguments? At a certain point, an interface could have so many type arguments that a developer using the interface could easily be confused by their individual meanings. Ideally, I could define a generic interface without burdening the implementer with explicitly specifying redundant, and possibly confusing, type information.